# Eloquent where condition AND ( condition OR condition OR condition )

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?
I want to get all projects with status 0 and if any of data matches in eloquent.
My code is like this

```
public function search(Request $request){
        if($request->has('q')){
            
            $search_query = $request->input('q');

            $projects = Project::where(['status' => '0'])->get();

            $projects = $projects->where(function($query) use ($search_query) {
                $query->where('title','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                      ->orWhere('shortDescription','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                      ->orWhere('longDescription','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                      ->orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%')
                      ->orWhere('projectLink','LIKE','%'.$search_query.'%');
            });
            $projects->get();

            dd($projects);
         }
}
```

> And I am getting this error
>
> ErrorException
> explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Comment: I resolved explode() problem. I was using get() twise. Now I have anoher issue. the querry is returning false everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem but changed the code a little bit... If you like, take it! I tested and it's working.

```
if($request->has('q')){

        // Your $request->q Value
        $term = $request->q;

        $projects = DB::table('tbl_projects')->where('status', '=', 0) 
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
                        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orWhere('shortDescription', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orWhere('longDescription', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orWhere('projectLink', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%');
                   })
                   ->get();

        //dd($projects);
    }
```

Raw query is:

```
select * from `tbl_projects` where `status` = 0 and (`title` LIKE %bla bla% or `shortDescription` LIKE %bla bla% or `longDescription` LIKE %bla bla% or `tags` LIKE %bla bla% or `projectLink` LIKE %bla bla%))
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is

```
$projects = Project::where(['status' => '0'])->get();
```

1. **(['status' => '0'])** Where clause params required is different. You must use **('status', '0')** or **('status', '=', '0')**
2. When you use **->get()**, you have a Collection or EloquentCollection object. You need a QueryBuilder

Try to implement a better programation logic.

A better implementation is

```
public function search(Request $request){
    if($request->has('q')){
         // Add array with field coincidences target. Is better if this array is a const static field in the Project model
        $searchFields = ['title', 'shortDescription', 'longDescription', 'tags', 'projectLink' ]; 
        // Now you can add 100 fields for search coincidences easily

        $search_query = $request->input('q');

        $projects = Project::where('status', '0');
        foreach($searchFields as $searchField){
            if ($searchField == 'title'){
                $projects = $projects->where($searchField,'LIKE',"%$search_query%");
                continue;
            }
               $projects = $projects->orWhere($searchField,'LIKE',"%$search_query%");
        }
        $projects = $projects->get();

        dd($projects);
     }
}
```

Comment: this will require every `searchField` to match in order to return a result.  change `$projects->where()` to `$projects->orWhere()`

Comment: @Erich You're right. Also I improved the answer for a better understanding

Comment: you had it better in the first version.  note you already have a `where` in the initial `$projects = Project::where('status', '0');` so the extra conditional inside `foreach` is unnecessary.  just make them all `orWhere`s.  :)

Comment: The reason I wanted to use orWhere clause is because I don't want to loop through. @hmrneves solution worked for me. Thanks a lot you all

Comment: A bit late for reply this, but for other users: I can't concat the second where with the `Project::where(status...` because the status condition isn't optional. I need `status = 0 AND (f = $q or f2 = $q ...)` Several years after this answer I still think that this solution is much better than the accepted one.